# Handler handler = new Handler() Ошибка: Handler is abstract; cannot be instantiated. Почему Android Studio импортирует не тот класс при автоимпорте?

Tags: android, android-studio

Воздействуя **Alt+Enter** на слово **Handler** Андроид-Студио вставило автоматом строку:

```
import java.util.logging.Handler;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Оказывается вместо строки:

```
import java.util.logging.Handler;
```

нужно вставлять:

```
import android.os.Handler;
```

Т.е. среда разработки импортирует не тот **Handler**. )

Поэтому и не работает, например: `handler.postDelayed( ... )` и т.д.

По *Alt+Enter* вставился импорт: `import java.util.logging.Handler` автоматом, без предоставления выбора!

Answer (score 8):

Поскольку вопрос касается больше проблем с автоимпортом, попробую прояснить ситуацию.
При следующих настройках автоимпорта (*Editor-> General -> Auto Import*):

- Все галочки в секциях XML и Java установлены
- Insert imports on paste -> All (влияет на импорт при копипасте кода)

[image: scrn]

Мы получим следующие настройки автоимпорта:

- Если импортируемый класс один (как, например, `Button`) во всех доступных для импорта API, то он будет автоматически импортирован без лишних вопросов.
- Если классов для импорта более одного (как класс `Handler`), то требуется нажать *Alt + Enter* на таком классе и будет предложен выбор в выпадающем меню, какой именно класс импортировать

[image: scrn]

- Если ни одного класса в коде не останется (будут удалены при редактировании кода), то и импорт этого класса будет удален автоматически

На мой взгляд это самая оптимальная настройка автоимпорта, которая не беспокоит в очевидных случаях и не своевольничает, если есть варианты выбора

Официальная [документация по настройке](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/auto-import.html) автоимпорта