# Как в Android Studio автоматически импортировать (import) классы?

Tags: android-studio, классы, импорт

Как в `Android Studio` автоматически импортировать (import) классы?

Answer (score 1):

*ответ был перенесен [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/779749/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%85-%D0%B2-intelli-idea), как несколько не соответствующий вопросу, на мой взгляд.*

`Settings -> Editor -> General -> Auto Import -> Insert imports on paste -> All|Ask|None`

> Используйте этот раскрывающийся список, чтобы определить, как IntelliJ
>   IDEA будет вставлять импорт для вставленных блоков кода, если они
>   содержат ссылки на классы, которые не импортируются в целевой класс.
>   Доступны следующие варианты:
>
> `All` - выберите этот параметр, чтобы IntelliJ IDEA автоматически
>   добавлял инструкции импорта для всех классов, которые находятся в
>   вставленном блоке кода и еще не импортированы в текущий класс.
>
> `Ask` - если этот параметр выбран, при вставке кодовых блоков IntelliJ
>   IDEA откроет диалоговое окно, в котором вы можете выбрать нужный
>   импорт.
>
> `None` - выберите этот параметр для подавления импорта.
>
> Если вы пропустите импорт, предложенный в режиме `Ask`, или выберите
>   режим `None`, не импортированные классы будут выделены красным цветом и
>   появится всплывающее окно импорта, которое поможет вам создавать
>   инструкции импорта с помощью сочетания клавиш `Alt + Enter`.

Также

`checkbox` - `Add unambiguous imports on the fly`(добавлять импорт на лету)

Установите этот флажок, чтобы IntelliJ IDEA автоматически добавлял импорт без вмешательства пользователя.

[Источник](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/auto-import.html)

*Мнение*

*C флажком выглядит эффектно. Удалил весь импорт классов из класса. IDE вставила их автоматически обратно. Опять же, какие там классы автоматом могут встать еще вопрос для меня. Пока что, автоматом, загружаются ровно те же классы, которые я прописывал вручную, по надобности.*

Comment: Немного [подробнее и с картинками](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/759838/177345) о работе автоимпорта - в ответ на *"какие там классы автоматом могут встать еще вопрос для меня"*

Comment: @pavlofff: спасибо, глянул